# Removing a file with only the python file object

Tags: python

Let's say that I open a file, that didn't previously exist, for writing:

```
f = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')
```

Once this line is executed the file '/tmp/test.txt' is created.  What is the cleanest way to remove (delete) the file with only the file object (f) and not the path?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot remove a file handle, only a file path, since multiple paths can [refer to the same file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) and some files (like sockets) don't even have paths. Therefore:

```
import os
f = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')
os.unlink(f.name)
# You can still use f here, it's just only visible for people having a handle.
# close it when you're finished.
```

**However, you should not do that** - there's a better way to solve your problem. Use the [**tempfile**](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module which deletes the file automatically, or just write to `/dev/null` if you just need a file handle and don't care about the content being written.

Answer (score 10):

Full answer:

```
f = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')
f.close()

os.remove(f.name)
```

You should close file before deleting (documentation says that it throws exception under Windows if the file is opened - didn't check this). `f` in your case is just a handle. It is not a file itself, so you can't delete it directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the file name from the `name` member and delete as usual:

```
In [1]: f = open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w')

In [2]: f.name
Out[2]: '/tmp/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you could also get away without creating a file at all. If all you need is a file-like object, most of the time you can use an instance of `io.StringIO` in place of a file. This can be useful to prevent unnecessary i/o operations.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> f=StringIO()
>>> f.write(u'Hello, world!')
13
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> f.read()
u'Hello, world!'
>>> f.close()
```